# Amazon S3 download link for public file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

I have public file that was uploaded to Amazon S3 through ruby gem 'aws-sdk-s3' and presigned_post, acl is set to 'public-read'.

Now I want to use simple html download link so file can be downloaded to user computer: `<a href="https://[bucket-name].s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/[file-key]" download>Save</a>`

Real sample file link for example: https://150yearssampleapp.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/2011-08-26+17.37.38.jpg

But when I click the link file is opened in new tab only. Tried Chrome ver. 97 and Safari ver. 15 browsers.

Read many topics but they all related to private files. It looks like public file should be easy to download. What am I doing wrong?

I can download file through server - so it get downloaded to server first and then sent to user browser but since file is public I want save time and let user download file directly from Amazon S3.

UPDATE 25.01.2022
So what I try to achieve - be able use one file for show and for download.

Comment: You may need to set the header / metadata Content-Disposition.

Comment: Thank you but isn't it a server-side operation, I think cannot be done via HTML code on the client. It can be used for example through response from rails controller on server side but I want to bypass server in this case since file is public and do not require authorisation.

Comment: @150Years No, you don't need the rails server in order to set the `Content-Disposition` header. You can set it on the S3 object directly.

Comment: How was the object uploaded? For example, the AWS CLI will set the `Content-Disposition` automatically based on the file type, but if you uploaded it via code then it would be blank. The `Content-Disposition` is used by the browser to determine what type of object it is.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Uploaded via code and presigned_post: `@s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "[key-name]", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read', content_type_starts_with: "")`. `Content-Type` set later depend on file type image or pdf. You are right `Content-Disposition` is blank. But if I set it to `attachment` on upload instead `inline` by default (I guess) will `img` tag process this file correctly? I need to show this images/files also. And does it mean if it was not set to `attachment` before I can not use file url to create downloadable link?